# ECS EC2 Instance unable to make HTTP requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, networking, amazon-ec2

Hi I am using ECS to run Docker tasks in EC2 instances. The tasks are run in Java and are looking to write to a SQS. The problem is my EC2 instance does not seem to be able to make any HTTP requests - this is what the Java error is when trying to write to that SQS Queue:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request. failed: connect timed out
```

I have tested command line commands such as curl and the connection also times out in the task but works fine if I connect and run it on the EC2 instance the task is being run on.

The same code via ECS runs fine in Fargate.
My EC2 instances are in public subnets, have a public IP assigned to them and the security group that is assigned to these instance have the following rules Inbound and Outbound:

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas as to why the tasks in these EC2 instances always timeout on HTTP requests thanks.

Edit(Adding Dockerfile) -
DockerFile:

```
FROM alpine/git as clone
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://GITLINK.git

FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=clone /app/aws_poll /app
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/target/aws-examples-1.0.jar /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["java -jar aws-sqs-examples-1.0.jar"]
HEALTHCHECK --interval=25s --timeout=3s --retries=2 CMD ["java", "HealthCheck", "||", "echo", "HEALTH CHECK:FAILED"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The EC2 Instance role has to be added as a resource that can use the SQS queue, in other words you need to modify the SQS Policy and add the EC2 instance role in the resource ARN, also make sure the instance role is allowed to talk to SQS by adding the relevant policy under IAM service.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but I already have a admin all access role assigned to the instances and sqs. Also the EC2 instance is able to connect to sqs queue and any http source. This seems to be a issue with docker not being able to connect via any http request

Comment: Can you open an interactive terminal with the container and try to communicate with the SQS service or try to resolve the queues URL with nslookup

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this Stefanos, when I connect to the EC2 instance pull the dockerfile, build and run it everything works perfect I see the expected output in my SQS portal with no java SQS http error. It seems to only not work when ECS initiates the task. The java is first checking if a queue with a name exists and if not then creates a new queue and sends a dummy message. This is the output when I run nslookup with the queue url on the task: nslookup https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/testQueue123282435861
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Comment: Looks like you cannot reach the SQS Queue from the ECS, are you sure your the policy that is attached in your Queue allows to be used by the ECS user/role, can't think of much more,  is your ECS behind a VPC?

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me and all your help, my EC2 instance was in a public subnet as per AWS docs when the EC2 instance is in a public subnet the task wont be able to make outside connections

Comment: Glad you figured this out!